# Trying to select link text within a table cell if the desired text is also within the cell

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

So I have a table cell that contains both text and a link. Now every row in this table has the same text link hyperlink title "[Details]" but the location changes on where it takes you based on which row you are in.

For example the cell will look like this: "Text I Want" [Details]

I want to be able to go to the correct link based on what text is also within that cell, but am having some issues figuring out how to code that in Python. Once a row in this table is clicked it moves it location in the table so using Xpath is out.

Here is what I've tried:

```py
MyText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='My Desired Text']")
MyText.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Details").click()
```

```py
def click_me(myString):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td/span[.='" + myString + "']//following::span[2]"))).click()

click_me("My Desired Text")
```

But I think I'll need to use `if` statements to actually get the desired results. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```html
<td>
                            <span>My Desired Text</span>
                            <span class="HSpacer10"></span>
                            <span class="commonLink" onclick="handleMyEvents(EVENT_EDIT_PKG, 60000,1);">[Details]</span>


                        </td>
```

Comment: Can you please share the html of the td with the text and link. Is link a child node of span or a sibling?

Comment: Added the html to my question above.

Comment: Try with this xpath `//span[normalize-space(.)='My Desired Text']/following-sibling::span[.='[Details]']`.

Comment: @supputuri couldn't find the element using that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the table is consisted of multiple texts and associated links with same text as **Details** you can write a method as follows:

```
def click_me(myString):
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td/span[.='" + myString + "']//following::span[2]"))).click()
```

Now you can call this method with any of the desired texts to click on the associated link:

```
click_me("My Desired Text")
# or
click_me("My Text")
# or
click_me("Text")
```

Comment: Just to clarify for myself, I should be replacing ```[.='" + myString + "']``` with ```[.='"My Desired Text"']``` correct?

Comment: @Loons22 No, Replace `My Desired Text` within `click_me("My Desired Text")` with the actual text. We are passing the actual string as a parameter to the method to click the associated link.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be able to find the element, keeps timing out. Replaced ```My Desired Text``` with the actual text and it still does not work while keeping the ```+ myString +``` in the code.

Comment: Ok so I changed it to the exact text I needed and this did work, but is there a way to do it where it will accept just part of the text? For example I did ```My Desired Text``` which didn't work because there is also a number at the end of that text. When I added that number, for example ```My Desired Text 1.00``` that did work.

Comment: @Loons22 It seems to be a different _usecase_ altogether. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please? StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.