# Selecting a link text in a cell based on other text within that cell

Tags: python, html, selenium

[Trying to select link text within a table cell if the desired text is also within the cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012678/trying-to-select-link-text-within-a-table-cell-if-the-desired-text-is-also-withi)

So an answer within that thread got me to where I am now regarding my question. This is what I have so far:

```py
def click_me(myString):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td/span[.='" + myString + "']//following::span[2]"))).click()

click_me("My Desired Text")
```

This does work, but there is usually a number at the end of `My Desired Text` such as `My Desired Text 1.00` that changes each time I navigate to a different page.

How do I make this work just using partial text such as `My Desired`?

Here is the HTML:

```html
<td>
                            <span>My Desired Text</span>
                            <span class="HSpacer10"></span>
                            <span class="commonLink" onclick="handleMyEvents(EVENT_EDIT_PKG, 60000,1);">[Details]</span>


                        </td>
```

Comment: Does the number matter or you want to click in the element with the text that starts with "My Desired Text"?

Comment: The number does not matter, I just need to be able to find "My Desired Text 1.00" cell using only say "My Desired"

Comment: Xpath provides a starts_with function you can use for that.

Comment: If you provide an example HTML, it would be possible to test exactly what you want, but I think this should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element that starts with the text you want.

Xpath provides functions you can use in your queries. The **starts-with** function seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

```
def click_me(myString):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td/span[starts-with(text(), '" + myString + "')]//following::span[2]"))).click()

click_me("My Desired Text")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is XPath [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function which is pretty much useful when you need to match an element basing on the partial text:

```
//td/span[contains(text(), '" + myString + "')]/following::span[2]
```

More information: [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)